# Python value not in list of objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check if a given value exists in a list of objects (stack).  Each object contains an attribute (state) that I want to check against.

Sample list:

```
[<state.State instance at 0x02A64580>, <state.State instance at 0x02A646E8>, <state.State instance at 0x02A649B8>]
```

What I have tried, doesn't seem to do it:

```
for neighbor in neighbors:
        if neighbor.state != any(s.state for s in stack):
            stack.append(neighbor)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `any()` returns a `bool`. It seems you expect it to do something else?

Comment: does it need to be `list`? If you'd have it as a dict where the value `state` would be as a key, then that would be much more convenient.

Comment: `if all(neighbor.state != s.state for s in stack):`

Comment: @roganjosh yes, bad use of any..

Comment: `not any` is equivalent to `all` (with the condition in the generator negated) and could be more readable: e.g. `if not any(neighbor.state == s.state for s in stack)`

Comment: Could also define `__eq__` on your `State` class to compare their `state` attributes, and then you could just use `if neighbor not in stack`.

Comment: @kindall thank you

Answer (score 0):

`any()` returns a `bool` that is true if any of the elements is true. It's basically a chained `or`.
I think what you might want is something like the following:

```
for neighbor in neighbors:
    present = False
    for s in stack:
        if neighbor.state == s.state:
            present = True
            break
    if not present:
        stack.append(neighbor)
```

Alternatively, you might want to use some kind of ordered set, like this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set. (Disclaimer: I did not test this package.)

Answer (score 0):

```
# setup
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

states = range(10)
objs = [MyObj(s) for s in states]

neighbor_states = [1,22,5,40,90]
neighbors = [MyObj(s) for s in neighbor_states]

# algorithm
for neighbor in neighbors:
    if neighbor.state not in (o.state for o in objs):
        objs.append(neighbor)

# testing      
for o in objs:
    print o.state
```